# What are the technical limitations when using Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am looking for information regarding the technical limitations when using Fusion Tables : - - how many rows can be stored in a Fusion Table
- how many queries (read/write) can be run simultaneously against a Fusion Table.
I could not find any info on https://developers.google.com
I asked a Google representative and he told me that Fusion Tables is still an experimental / beta product, and I shall check out at stackoverflow.

I plan to develop an application where users will update attributes of specific locations. I would like to use Fusion Tables so that locations and their attributes are stored in a Fusion Table.
The application will involve a lot of read/updates of the table (up to 500 000 read/update queries in one minute), with up to 3 000 000 locations registered in the Fusion Table so I wonder if I will be limited by the technology, technically or regarding the terms of service.

My impression is that Fusion Tables are not really supposed to be updated with such a high frequency.

Answer (score 15):

There are a number of limitations to consider:

- 25,000 requests/day
- 250MB space per table
- A cell of data in Fusion Tables supports a maximum of 1 million characters
- [Insert Limits](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#insertRow)

  - Maximum data size for a single HTTP request is 1MB
  - Total number of table cells being added cannot exceed 10,000 cells (not rows!)
  - A single request may contain up to a maximum of 500 `INSERT` statements
- Only the first 100,000 records are mapped or included in spatial query results
- When viewed on a map, map tiles may exceed the 500 feature-per-tile limit, and features will be dropped from the map

Please note that the last two limits above are described in a [deprecated section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Geo), I couldn't find newer documentation about it. Maybe the limit does no longer exist or it just has not yet been documented. But the limits certainly apply if you are using [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) to to display data on Google Maps.

[FusionTablesLayer limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesLimits):

- Max. 5 layers per map
- Only to one of those layers styles can be applied
- Max. 5 styles may be applied on this layer
- Only the first 100,000 rows of data in a table are mapped or included in query results
- Map tiles may exceed the 500 feature-per-tile limit, and features will be dropped from the map

If you are a [Google Maps Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) customer, some of the limits can be modified.

Comment: What happens after number of request increases the limit? Also, if I create an application using an API key, does the number of hits per user of the application or total number of hits by the application count?

Comment: Also, do you have an idea of about what are the charges if one wishes to to increase the limits?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think the 25'000 request/day are refering to requests done with your API key. But you can request more requests in the API console if you need more. I don't know about the charges for increase the limits. It's probably best to [ask Google directly](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html).