# Fusion Table Point Query

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with just over 611,000 data lines.  Each line represents a point over the US with that is located at 0.05 degree grid spacing in lat and long.  Each data row contains a lat and long column along with 8 other columns of data.  I want to query the data table based on a user entered address.  I have looked at:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow

What is the best way to locate and display the single data point closest to the user entered address?

Here is my table ID:

```
1Rb-F5w3U_WKT9zfT_WbTczLnBk7VZNge0JkVVuU
```

Comment: I don't think that you can find a better solution than the one from your link. Because Google Fusion Tables doesn't yet support that many spatial query functions. Please keep in mind, that [Fusion Tables is currently limited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954718/549755), so only the first 100,000 records are mapped or included in spatial query results.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am aware of the 100,000 limit and am trying to work around it.  Thanks again.