# How to know that Fusion Tables usage is over limit?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I use Fusion Tables API to add rows to my tables. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954718/604388) explaining the limits. Will I get some error message when these limits are reached?

I am getting currently the following error

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/my-table-id/import?uploadType=media&alt=json
>   returned "Internal error when processing import.  Please try again.">

and don't know what is the reason.

Total number of rows in my document is 464'938. Number of cells is 13 * 464'938 (non-empty cells - 5'295'364). Downloaded file size is 43M (not sure how to check file size directly on Google side). But when I've created new table, it started to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a capacity limit was hit.

In December 2015, Fusion Tablkes [announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fusion-tables-announce/4oB11Lpd4z8) increased limits.

> We are happy to announce that, starting immediately:
>
> All users have 1 GB of storage quota for their tables. There continues
>   to be a 250 MB limit per table.
>
> Newly created tables can show up to 350,000 features on a map.  There
>   continues to be a limit of 1 M characters per cell and 10 M vertices
>   per table. You can activate the new limit for existing tables by
>   opening the row editor and then clicking the “Save” button.

If you try again it may work, but 465k rows is still high.