# Does the number of rows count towards the API rate limit in Google Fusion importRows?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have been getting intermittent 500 errors while batch-uploading simple row data to Google Fusion Tables via the v2 API, using the importRows method.

We have tried throttling and backing off, but the patterns seem to indicate that we are going over quota even with small numbers of requests and fairly slow rates.

I can see in the API console it's limited to 200 requests / 100s (as confirmed in other posts it's a 0.5/s rate limit).

We are about to sadly abandon the Fusion Tables API and rebuild the entire project using something else, due to the unpredictable nature of the 500 errors. (Sometimes insert happens but sometimes not, after an error is returned which makes retrying run the risk of duplicate inserts).

It occurred to me that as we are uploading 1,000 rows per request, does this count as 1,000 requests?

Answer (score 1):

Are you uploading media files when you make an importRows request? It could be that you're exceeding table storage limits (250MB per table). You may want to check your code and data payloads against this and other Fusion Table limitations.

Here's a good reference on the limits of Fusion Tables:

[What are the technical limitations when using Fusion Tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952166/what-are-the-technical-limitations-when-using-fusion-tables)

Comment: No it's just a small amount of data per row. It's an intermittent problem so continuing later usually works, hence it can't be over a permanent limit per table. Also the error says "try again" (which seems counter-intuitive for a 500 error to me).

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe you can try reducing the number of rows uploaded per request (try stress testing with row counts under 200). Also when the server responds with a 500 error did you get any details describing the error? That might help with diagnosing the problem.